# Are regional accents disappearing?

Tags: accent

Maybe this fits better on Skeptics @ SE?

---

There is an idea that is frequently seen that states that regional accents are disappearing:

- [Regional accents are disappearing: which do you want to save?](https://www.shortlist.com/news/regional-accents-are-disappearing-which-do-you-want-to-save)
- [Regional Accents Are Disappearing and the North is Slowly Dying, Study Says](https://www.vice.com/en_uk/article/xd375n/regional-dialects-are-more-or-less-disappearing-and-the-north-is-slowly-dying-study-says)
- [Why City Accents Are Fading in the Midwest](https://www.citylab.com/life/2018/04/why-city-accents-are-fading-in-the-midwest/555152/)
- [Fuhgeddaboudit: New York Accent On Its Way Out, Linguists Say](https://www.npr.org/2015/02/02/383289958/fuhgeddaboudit-new-york-accent-on-its-way-out-linguists-say)

Multiculturalism and globalization often get blamed as the culprit for why accents are disappearing. Digital media and Hollywood, in a similar vein, are also often accused - saying that people all end up with "TV accents."

Is there any proof that regional accents are actually disappearing?

Comment: Very interesting question, but I am not sure this is the right place to ask...it is also a POB issue to some extent.

Comment: This is a question is  for the Linguists site https://linguistics.stackexchange.com and should be migrated there.

Comment: Nah, this is just a result of popular media fads. There is a lot of change in dialects, but without proper surveys all reports are impressionistic and biased. I seriously doubt there is much difference in the way people actually talk -- only, perhaps, in the breadth of the dialects they can understand, due to the spread of Anglophone movies and TV.

Answer (score 10):

There are two questions here, one about the phenomenon, is it actually the case that regional accents are disappearing, and the other, what is the cause of such disappearance.

It is incontrovertible that accents (and entire languages) are disappearing. The articles you give links to refer to scientific articles that show that fewer and fewer people are speaking like their grandparents and more likely to speak the standard accent. There are many ways to show that an accent is going away but the simplest is simply a single point of many possible, the loss of post-vocalic 'r' in England.

[image: loss of 'r']

[From 'Why r is not always pronounced in England'](https://languageoficeandfire.tumblr.com/post/119202835455/why-is-r-not-always-pronounced-in-british).

This picture shows the accents with 'r' in England, in the 1950's on the left and the 2000's on the right. There is a noticeable loss of people who don't drop the 'r'. A way to describe this is that the regional accents in England are becoming less distinct which is to say disappearing. Surely this is only one specific phenomenon, but it is one of many. There may still currently be a West Country pirate-like accent with its strong r's, but fewer and fewer people are speaking like that. Similarly, but in the other direction on the other side of the Atlantic, Boston or New York area or Southern accents which were traditionally r-less, are more likely to pronounce all their r's.

But this all shows that there is evidence that some features are being lost in a very general sense. There's also incontrovertible evidence that full languages, not just minor variants, are going extinct now around the world. So maybe you're asking if, specifically for English, whether of the the many labeled varieties out there in the US and Canada, UK, Australia, and other places, if any of those have just ... gone away. Surely, Geordie and Scouse and West Country and Estuary are all still around (and from movies and TV seem to all be going strong). And Saturday Night Live seems to be the place to do previously unnoteworthy accents of California and Philadelphia. On the other hand, I've noticed that people from the Southern US on TV interviews tend to surprisingly not 'have' an accent (regular people, not politicians). What I'm saying with all this is that it is unclear if the named varieties are being washed away, or if their distinctions are being encouraged, if non-standard varieties are losing speakers or gaining. That, as John Lawler hinted at in one of his comments, would take a lot more comprehensive research.

---

As to why any of this may (or may not) be happening though, that is a different matter. (note that the link I gave is titled 'Why' but there is only description in the text, little causal analysis).

One thing that is sure is that populations that are nearby and speak with each other tend to share language features, even if they are from entirely historically different speech populations (see [Sprachbund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachbund)). So it is almost boring to explain loss of distinctions, and eventually loss of accents (and even entire languages) by appealing to mass communication and globalization. The socially more prestige accents tend to hang around longer than the low prestige varieties.

Answer (score 9):

The reports of dialect death are greatly exaggerated. Yes, some homogenization of dialect features including phonology is occurring. At the same time, we're also seeing some divergence through the development of new dialects. For example, take the following quote expressing dire distress:

> The dialects are dying, and the competent helpers who understand them are waxing old. In a few years it will be too late.

This was from a letter written by W. W. Skeat in 1895 (as included in *[English in Nineteenth-Century England](https://books.google.com/books?id=W3BPksr1VQoC&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=%22The%20dialects%20are%20dying,%20and%20the%20competent%20helpers%20who%20understand%20them%20are%20waxing%20old.%20In%20a%20few%20years%20it%20will%20be%20too%20late.%22&source=bl&ots=g-MLF75kXR&sig=ACfU3U3fq9J0z7ZwYQYuui575wWV5ePfag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG65GUr8PiAhUjmuAKHUTnCW0Q6AEwA3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20dialects%20are%20dying%2C%20and%20the%20competent%20helpers%20who%20understand%20them%20are%20waxing%20old.%20In%20a%20few%20years%20it%20will%20be%20too%20late.%22&f=false)*, 1999). Skeat, a professor of Anglo Saxon at Oxford and an eminent philologist, was appealing for funding for the *English Dialect Dictionary*, a monumental project that sought to preserve a record of dialects before they were lost to more standardized forms of English promoted in primary education. His prediction was premature. The continued existence of many dialects today suggests that dialects are more robust than Skeat presumed, even if some may die, transform, or merge over time.

On this point, Joan C. Beal (*An Introduction to Regional Englishes*, 2010) suggests that Skeat and other dialect enthusiasts were reacting to one kind of dialect change (a perceived loss of rural dialects) while not acknowledging the development of new urban dialects like Scouse, Geordie, Brummie, Cockney, and Manc (p. 6). Furthermore, such development may likely continue, as new "supralocal" or reigonal varieties may begin to emerge.

On this point, *[The Routledge Handbook of Language and Superdiversity](https://books.google.com/books?id=2kBNDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT207&ots=_axACcC4QI&dq=%22The%20dialects%20are%20dying%2C%20and%20the%20competent%20helpers%20who%20understand%20them%20are%20waxing%20old.%20In%20a%20few%20years%20it%20will%20be%20too%20late.%22&pg=PT217#v=onepage&q&f=false)* ("Dialect as Heritage," again by Beal, 2018) explains one recent counterforce to the loss of dialects: heritage movements that argue for the *authenticity* of the original dialect. From kitschy mugs to local language classes, proponents of local dialects receive a lot of attention from both fellow locals and tourists. For example, look at this mug sold in [Tyne & Wear Archives and Museums](https://www.twmuseums.org.uk/), which features the local Geordie dialect:

[image]

There are also many resources (including [online](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/case-studies/geordie/lexis/)) that seek to preserve the dialect. Most importantly, local speakers seem to carry on its speech patterns generationally. The prognosis for Geordie is good: this introduction to recent phonetic changes in Geordie and nearby dialects (from *[Urban North-Eastern England: Tyneside to Teesside](https://books.google.com/books?id=eV9MyzOnBi8C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22Recent%20studies%20which%20have%20compared%20the%20speech%20of%20the%20young%20with%20that%20of%20older%20speakers%20in%20order%20to%20infer%20change%20in%20progress%20in%20the%20community%20have%20found%20evidence%20pointing%20to%20current%20changes%20taking%20place%20in%20the%20varieties%20of%20the%20region.%22&source=bl&ots=KI3_YGBPKz&sig=ACfU3U3PNNBOKWR4G8Eel68uArjKlua8Vw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq2f7iu8PiAhUFU98KHe31Ar8Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Recent%20studies%20which%20have%20compared%20the%20speech%20of%20the%20young%20with%20that%20of%20older%20speakers%20in%20order%20to%20infer%20change%20in%20progress%20in%20the%20community%20have%20found%20evidence%20pointing%20to%20current%20changes%20taking%20place%20in%20the%20varieties%20of%20the%20region.%22&f=false)*, 2012) represents a healthy range of homogenization and increasing diversity in phonology:

> Recent studies which have compared the speech of the young with that of older speakers in order to infer change in progress in the community have found evidence pointing to current changes taking place in the varieties of the region. In some respects, the varieties **appear to be becoming more homogeneous** as highly localised forms are being used to a lesser degree in the speech of the young. In other ways, varieties **can be said to be diverging** or at least **maintaining a level of distinctiveness** as changes are adopted to differing degrees and with modifications throughout the region. (p. 43)

So yes, sounds are definitely homogenizing between dialects, but it's not clear that the loss of any individual sound (like rhoticization) universally leads to the loss of a dialect or accent altogether. Instead, these changes are part of a broader set of changes that may lead to the loss of some dialects and the formation of new ones. As an illustration of continued phonological diversity, look at this table, again from *An Introduction to Regional Englishes*, p. 22:

[image]

Most regional dialects have three or more distinguishing phonemes from standard English. Yes, sometimes the one region and another share many of the same phonetic features (see S. Midlands and East Anglia), but at least one phonetic difference still distinguishes them. There are also dialect differences not represented on the table because they go beyond phonetics. So the health of one's local dialect may vary, but perceptions of utter dialect death overstate the influences of industrialization and mass media.

Comment: As a general note, I really recommend *An Introduction to Regional Englishes* if you're interested in learning about how dialects work and change. It is well-researched, which is one reason I found myself returning to it for a source here.

Comment: ... It's also a wonderful example of countification.

Answer (score 5):

What changes accents is not ‘globalisation’, or, at least, not that alone.  Nor is it as simple as TV or mass media.  People (not all people, but most people) are influenced by the people around them.  Also, accents have constantly been changing.  We now know that the ‘upper class’ accent of Queen Elizabeth II’s daughter, Princess Anne, has shifted over the past 40 years towards a more ordinary ‘standard’ or ‘BBC’ accent.

The force that changes accent is probably the same that produces  changes of species: natural selection.  Over time, for example, the teutonic languages of the Saxon and Vikings gradually evolved into English, because of the contact between invaders and invaded.   Before them in continental Europe the Latin language gradually shifted into French in one place, Italian in another, Spanish, Portuguese and Romanian in others.

Later, British colonial and criminal activity produced the accents of Australia, New Zealand and, by the way, the United States and Canada.  It produced the accents of Republic of South Africa and Zimbabwe (the white populations, at least).

In the late middle ages English underwent a ‘great vowel shift’, the precise reason for which is not fully clear.

The mass media may have some influence.  But it is often exaggerated.  It is interesting that even though European continental rock, TV and film have been in the post war period dominated by American material, this did not produce an American style accent, as it has to a greater extent in East Asia.  That is more likely to be a matter of how they are taught English and (in some cases) by whom.

This brings me onto the teaching of English.  In the U.K. (or at least in England), there is one unique feature, mentioned by Greenbaum in his Oxford English Grammar:  **a non-regional upper class accent**.  This has been the accent of all upper (and often middle class people born anywhere in England and educated in private schools).  This became standard English pronunciation.

So the published phonic rules that govern the teaching of literacy in compulsory schools are those of ‘standard English’ - often thought of as the ‘middle class accent’.  That will tend to move many children in the Northern, Eastern and South Western parts of the country away from the regional accents of there parents.   It is true that more and more schoolchildren do speak something nearer to ‘standard English.

This has not happened in Scotland, Wales or Northern Ireland to anything like that extent.  This is partly because of national pride in the language. There are upper and lower class accents in Scotland, but they are all rhotic and manifestly Scottish.

I cannot speak for the US, but much the same may apply.  The influences at work are a mixture of population mobility, mass media, compulsory mass education and whatever may be the prevailing approach to literacy (including phonics), fashion and, last but not least, the desire for social status.

The processes of natural selection are slow and imperceptible.  But they can be accelerated by increase in agents of change:  communication, education, population movement, and perhaps social attitudes and aspirations.

I shall probably be judged off topic for this, but there it is.

Comment: The OP wisely asks *Is there any proof?* Impressions and opinions are good and interesting to read but how much should I trust your evaluation? Not saying that I disagree about the Scots and the Irish maintaining their distinct accents, but maybe those too have softened or broadened over the generations.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I do not say that they have not changed at all.  But they have remained recognisably Scottish.  Also, as I have said, the upper class accent has also changed.  The British have adopted some American ways of saying things.  I (and Brits generally) grew up saying ‘Hárass’, where most now say ‘haráss’.  I just look for a synonym!  Globalisation is too simple.  I left out the completely wild idea that more women going out to work, combined with compulsory schooling and the rise of numbers attending university could well have contributed to the reduction of home influence.

Comment: I want to upvote because the answer is well written and presented but... dammit I will.

Comment: @Tuffy: But Americans are now saying hárassment instead of harássment.

Comment: @PeterShor a really?  Well I never!

Comment: @PeterShor Sadly, the entire Australian population aged under 30 now says *a bunch of* Americanisms like *cóntroversy* rather than *a number of* BritE conventions like *contróversy*. It won't be long before our schools are teaching that *aluminium* only has one "i". *Sigh...*

Comment: @Chappo you may or may not be aware but Peter Shore is American. Cambridge, Massachusetts, not Cambridgeshire UK. The US is the world super power, it has the money, it dictates the fashions where language is concerned.  It's only natural that Australian youth is more influenced by American culture. The British empire with its unnatural impositions on the most diverse cultures has long dissipated, and good thing too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, well aware of the esteemed Mr Shor's geographic base, and also of the inevitability of US hegemony. My lamentations were the feeble whisper of an ageing Aussie generation that grew up with US sitcoms but British sensibilities.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Cheers!

Comment: [Albanian is no child of Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_language).

Answer (score 1):

"This was from a letter written by W. W. Skeat in 1895 (as included in English in Nineteenth-Century England, 1999). Skeat, a professor of Anglo Saxon at Oxford and an eminent philologist, was appealing for funding for the English Dialect Dictionary, a monumental project that sought to preserve a record of dialects before they were lost to more standardized forms of English promoted in primary education. His prediction was premature."

Arguably many of the dialects of that time were lost and homogenised, but language change continues.

You see, in the past features tended to spread out from a 'centre of prestige' (such as London) in waves and ripples over time (wave theory, a very well accepted model in sociolinguistics). But by the time such features had reached the edges of say, England or Britain, the language in London would already have its own new innovations which would be starting to ripple out again. So over time, features that had initially been London features that had replaced features from a previous dialect, themselves come to be viewed as 'regionalisms', because none of the middle classes have them and all the areas surrounding the influential population centres no longer have them.

How the media/globalisation is effecting language change we don't know for sure yet, but the early signs are that it can influence language change at a faster rate and over great distances (instant exposure, vs ripples of features taking many years to reach the borders of non-mobile societies).

This is not to say that regional differences will be completely lost if Anglo-American influence in the media continue to dominate, some features will be adopted, others will be dropped, some local features will be kept as identity markers, others will be dropped and replaced.

And by the time many of these new features have become fully adopted by a speech community in Australia/Ireland/wherever, it's likely that the source country of many of these innovations (most likely the USA) will have gone through its own innovations, thus maintaining regional differences.

So even if everybody in Ireland ends up sounding exactly like Americans currently do (I chose Ireland as an example because I'm familiar with the work of Trinity Colleges head of linguistics, Jeffrey Kallen, who claims that future generations in Ireland are likely to have highly Americanised accents among many classes in society if the current trend there continues), regional difference would still likely be maintained, because by the time new features became settled in Ireland, the US dialect would have moved on.

Comment: Please note that your opening paragraph is a quote from another answer from user TaliesinMerlin, and do include other citations to support your answer.  Here is the [tour] of the site and [help], and welcome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).